# How to perform a limit in a loop using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Need a little help here. And sorry for my wrong title if it confused you. Right now I am creating a table guide for indexing company name.
I need to limit the column of table by 40.

So every rows is 40 columns. And the continuation of the display will be going to the next row.
I have a code like this but I don't have an idea how to include the next rows .

```
<?php

        $company_list = db_get_array('SELECT company FROM cscart_companies ORDER BY company');

        $div = $total /40; //set rows EX: 22

        echo "<table border='1'>";

            foreach($company_list as $company_details){

                if($div != 0){

                    $counter = 1; //set for columns

                    if($counter == 40){
                        //create another row
                    }else{
                        //add new column
                        echo "<td>".strtoupper(substr($company_details['company'],0,3))."</td>";
                        $counter++;
                    }

                }else{
                    //exit loop and <tr>
                }

                $div--;

            }

        echo "</table>"; 

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs a lot in programming - that is collecting groups of things from a larger set. You're on the right track, and there are many ways to accomplish this. This is one way...

```
$counter = 0;
$group = array();
echo "<table>";
foreach ($company_list as $company_details) {

    if ($counter == 40) {
      // output one row (40 records)
      echo "<tr>" . join("\n", $group) . "</tr>"; 

      // reset the counter and empty the group
      $counter = 0;
      $group = array();
    } 

    // add one record to the group array and increment the counter
    $group[] = "<td>" . strtoupper(substr($company_details['company'],0,3)) . "</td>";
    ++$counter;
}

// output any remaining records
if (count($group) > 0)
  echo "<tr>" . join("\n", $group) . "</tr>"; 

// close the table
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the very informative answer. I will try it and study as well. Thanks.

Comment: Ok sir. How can I include what row is the column? In the table every column there is a corresponding row count. For example in row 1. Before the columns for indexes. There should be An indication in the first column what row it is.